# Converting tflearn model to keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to convert my old tflearn model into a keras model, as I have migrated from TF 1.15 to TF 2.0, where tflearn isn't supported anymore. 
My keras model is:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(None, len(train_x[0]))),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation="softmax"),
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(train_x, train_y)
print("Tested Acc:", test_acc)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 3
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (49, 51)

I have no clue how to fix this error. Do I need to redimensionate the model somehow? What am I doing wrong?

For reference, my old tflearn model was:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, show_metric=True)
```

Comment: There is no need to give the batch dimension in the `input_shape` parameter. See [the Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense).

Comment: Good to know. I have removed them, but obviously they haven't solved my main issue, the valueerror

Comment: This should have reduced the input shape accordingly. Can you give the output of `mode.summary()`?

Comment: If I comment out both model.compile and model.fit and do the model.summary(), I get: Model: "sequential"
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   

dense (Dense)                (None, None, 8)           416       
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 8)           72        
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, None, 6)           54        
Total params: 542
Trainable params: 542
Non-trainable params: 0

Comment: So does the input shape of the first Dense layer match your expectations and the shape of the data in `train_x`?

Comment: The value error with "expected dense_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (49, 51)"
traces back to my line with the model.fit(model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs)

Comment: Well the shape is None, none, 8 which I don't think my data for train_x should be

Comment: Yes. Can you update the code in your question so that the `None` no longer appears in the `input_shape` and give the dimension of `train_x`, i.e. the output of `print(train_x.shape)`?

Comment: Okay so I changed it to: input_shape=51.
So that gave me the error: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
I then changed it to input_shape=[51].
It started training, but after 32/49 it stopped with the error:
"ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 6 for 'metrics/accuracy/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,6]."

Comment: My guess is that `train_y.shape` is `(6,)` and not `(1,)` as expected by `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, so the evaluation after the first batch fails. Switch to `categorical_crossentropy` instead and make sure to check out the documentation.

Comment: Wow that worked. I must admit I really didn't read anything about the loss models. I guess I should go back and do that. Thank you so much!
1 last question: The reason I switched from tf 1.15 to tf 2 with keras was a need to run multiple models in the same module. Do you know if it is better to run all the models in the same module vs spacing them out in different modules?

Comment: Glad I could help! I will type up a proper answer, please consider upvoting and accepting it. Regarding the last question, I suggest you do some research first and then open a new, clearly focused question.

Comment: I will and thank you very much. You have been so helpful. Something that has amazed me since I started learning python 1,5 years ago, is how helpful the coding community is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we uncovered in the comments, there are two issues with your code.

First, you must not give the batch dimension in the `input_shape` parameter, cf. [the Keras documentation for `Dense`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#dense).

Second, since `train_y.shape = (?, 6)`, you need to use `categorical_crossentropy` and not `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. There is [a note in the Keras documentation](https://keras.io/losses/#is_categorical_crossentropy) which describes the difference in detail.

Here is the corrected code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]))),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation="softmax"),
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
```